# Deployment error: Apex class has Batchable or Future jobs pending or in progress; Schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress

Tags: deployment, scheduled-apex

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy code using ANT to one for my sandboxes:

> "Apex class has Batchable or Future jobs pending or in progress;
>   Schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress"

They problem is that when I look at the Apex Jobs logs I see that all jobs are either Aborted or Complete and in the Scheduled Jobs logs there is no job with 'Next Scheduled Run' date.

So, I'm not sure why I am getting this error and more important how do I work around this and get the code deployed.

Comment: Hi Have you checked deploying by any other way, apart from ANT

Comment: @SravanAlaparthi Its not working even whwn I try to copy/past the class in Eclipse