# Apex class has Batchable or Future jobs pending or in progress

Tags: apex, deployment, ant

I am deploying to production using the Ant migration tool. Every class is reporting the error: Apex class has Batchable or Future jobs pending or in progress
Even classes such as StringUtils and such which have not future or batchable methods.

Someone asked a similar question here
[Deployment error: Apex class has Batchable or Future jobs pending or in progress; Schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23045/deployment-error-apex-class-has-batchable-or-future-jobs-pending-or-in-progress)
but it was closed for comment because it was a duplicate of this post:
[Ghost Schedulable Classes Blocking Deployment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/ghost-schedulable-classes-blocking-deployment)

But that post does not answer my problem.  Nor does the SF posted help here:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187051&language=en_US

Comment: The time I had the exact problem you're facing, but in Eclipse, I ended up solving it by deleting the project and redownloading it again. Guess it was all Eclipse's fault.
Don't know really how to solve this for Ant, however. Sorry!

Comment: Have you contacted Salesforce support as suggested in the question you linked to?

Comment: Is `StringUtils` ultimately called by another Apex Batchable or Future class? This dependency could explain why you still get the error with a seemingly unrelated class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suddenly the problem went away.

I suspect that ONE job was active even though I could not see any via this query:
SELECT ApexClassId,CreatedDate,ExtendedStatus,Id,JobItemsProcessed,JobType,MethodName,NumberOfErrors,ParentJobId,Status,TotalJobItems FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE status!='Completed' AND status!='Aborted' AND status != 'Failed' 
As suggested in this SF solution https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187051&language=en_US

I suspect this running job blocked all classes and produced misleading error messages.  After all StringUtils and 90% of the classes had no future methods nor are they batchable classes.

In any case, the problem went away without any action on my part.

Answer (score 7):

1. go to Setup > Administration > Monitoring > Apex Jobs and abort all pending jobs
2. go to Setup > App > Develop > Apex Classes and hit `Compile all classes`
3. re-run your ant deploy target

Any luck?

Comment: I should have made it clear that there was no running jobs of any kind, that I could see.   I ran the query below to find active jobs and the result was empty list.   SELECT ApexClassId,CreatedDate,ExtendedStatus,Id,JobItemsProcessed,JobType,MethodName,NumberOfErrors,ParentJobId,Status,TotalJobItems FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE status!='Completed' AND status!='Aborted' AND status != 'Failed'

Comment: @bigassforce How do you delete apex jobs? I don't see any "Delete" buttons or anything like that.